# How to get move, swap and compare count for quicksort in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote some code snippet in order to get move, swap and compare count for quicksort in C++, but it only gave me compare count. Didn't find a good answer in google. Can someone have a look at the following code and give me some clue? Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>
uint64_t swapcnt, cmpcnt, defaultctorcnt, argctorcnt, copyctorcnt, assigncnt, movecnt;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start, end;

class MyData {
public:
    MyData();
    MyData(int n);
    MyData(const MyData& rhs) {argctorcnt++; data = rhs.data; }
    MyData(MyData&& rhs) {movecnt++; data = rhs.data; }
    MyData& operator=(const MyData& rhs) {copyctorcnt++; if(this==&rhs) return *this; data=rhs.data; return *this;}
    MyData& operator=(const MyData&& rhs) {movecnt++; if(this==&rhs) return *this; data=rhs.data; return *this;}
  bool operator==(const MyData& ohs) const {cmpcnt++; return data==ohs.data;}
    ~MyData();
    bool operator<(const MyData& oh) const;
    void set(int n){data=n;}
    void swap(MyData& rhs) {
        int tmp = data;
        data = rhs.data;
        rhs.data = tmp;
        swapcnt++;
    }
private:
    int data;
};

namespace std{
template<>
void swap(MyData& lhs, MyData& rhs) {
    swapcnt++;
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
}

MyData::MyData() {
    data=0;defaultctorcnt++;
}

MyData::MyData(int n) {
    data=n; argctorcnt++;
}
MyData::~MyData() {

}
bool MyData::operator<(const MyData& rhs) const {
    cmpcnt++;
    return data<rhs.data;
}

template <class ForwardIt>
 void quicksort(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
 {
    if(first == last) return;
    auto pivot = *std::next(first, std::distance(first,last)/2);
    ForwardIt middle1 = std::partition(first, last,
                         [pivot](const auto& em){ return em < pivot; });
    ForwardIt middle2 = std::partition(middle1, last,
                         [pivot](const auto& em){ return !(pivot < em); });
    quicksort(first, middle1);
    quicksort(middle2, last);
 }

void clearcnts() {
    swapcnt=0, cmpcnt=0; defaultctorcnt=0, argctorcnt=0, copyctorcnt=0, assigncnt=0; movecnt=0;
}

template<typename T>
void checkresult(std::string name, T& datasorted, T&  dataset2) {
    if(!std::equal(datasorted.begin(), datasorted.end(), dataset2.begin(), dataset2.end()))
        std::cout <<name << " sort result " << "not equal"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << name <<"\t compare count "
            <<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(10)<< cmpcnt
            << ", swap count " <<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(10)<< swapcnt
            <<", defaultctorcnt="<<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(2)<< defaultctorcnt
            <<", argctorcnt="<<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(10)<<argctorcnt
            <<", copyctorcnt=" <<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(10)<<copyctorcnt
            <<", assigncnt="<<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(2)<<assigncnt
            <<", movecnt="<<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(10)<<movecnt
            <<", total="<<std::dec<<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(10)<<swapcnt + cmpcnt + defaultctorcnt + argctorcnt + copyctorcnt + assigncnt+movecnt
            <<" in " <<std::setfill(' ')<<std::setw(6)<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms"<<std::endl;
}
void sortn(int cnt) {
    std::vector<MyData> dataset(cnt);
    srand (time(NULL));
    for(auto& data:dataset) // thanks to the answer from Rumburak
        data.set( rand());
    std::vector<MyData> datasorted=dataset;
    std::sort(datasorted.begin(), datasorted.end());
    {
        std::vector<MyData> dataset2=dataset;
        clearcnts();
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        quicksort(dataset2.begin(), dataset2.end());
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        checkresult("quicksort", datasorted, dataset2);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int cnt = 102400*54;
    if(argc>1)
        cnt=atoi(argv[1]);
    std::cout << "check compare and swap when sorting " <<cnt << " objects" << std::endl; //
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++) {
        std::cout << i << "th execution\n";
        sortn(cnt);
        usleep(rand()%37+5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To build the code: g++ -o qsortcnt -std=c++1y qsortcnt.cpp

With the help from Rumburak, now the program seems produce reasonable output:
Output of the program: quicksort        compare count  254998866, swap count   56669398, defaultctorcnt= 0, argctorcnt=  27611745, copyctorcnt=         0, assigncnt= 0, movecnt=         0, total= 339280009 in   4794 ms

I am using gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) in Cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: You seem to be assuming `std::partition()` will call your overloaded `swap()` function but I don't think this is guaranteed (and obviously isn't happening). The possible implementation shown on the cppreference.com page where you copied your `quicksort()` function from uses `std::iter_swap`, for example.

Comment: I guess(just a guess) you are using MAC OS or FreeBSD where it alias g++ to clang, as g++ has not yet implement decltype(auto) in C++14. For a Linux user with clang and libc++ installed, I believe compiling line should be clang -o qsortcnt  -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ qsortcnt.cpp -lc++

Comment: I expect my specialized version of std::swap<> is called, not the overloaded version. when things does not work, I just give a try by adding the overloaded swap, but it didn't help.  Thanks for pointing out std::iter_swap, not sure if there is a way to make std::partition use a specialized version of std::iter_swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the way you count. It is here:

```
for(auto data:dataset) // This line is incorrect
    data.set( rand()); // dataset is not affected by this line
```

You are iterating over *values* of `dataset` here. That means that you are modifying copies of the values in `dataset`. And `dataset` itself remains unchanged.

As a result, there is nothing for your `quicksort` to do. All the values are default constructed and equal. Thus, `dataset` is already sorted. No swapping is required.

By turning `data` into a reference, you get what you want:

```
for(auto& data:dataset) // The & is required to take references
    data.set( rand());  // Now dataset is affected by this line
```

Now you will see reasonable values for your counts.

If you feel unsure as to why the `&` is required, there is a [great talk by Scott Meyers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU). It will tell you everything you need to know about that topic and then some.

Comment: I don't understand how those lines are related to the problem of getting move, swap and compare count for quicksort in C++.

Comment: OK, I turned the hint into an explanation with solution.

Comment: You are my hero! I thought you are kidding at first. but at last I am a fool.